What is the appropriate test comparing two groups with pre-post design?
I have two groups (control and experimental), both have pre- and post-test scores.
A colleague of mine suggested that I use a one-way MANOVA to test the effectiveness of the intervention, with pre- and post-scores as dependent variables.
It seems to me completely wrong, as the two scores are paired. Moreover, why should I consider and analyze the pre score as dependent? after all I am not testing the effect of the intervention on the pre-test score but only on the post-test score.
As I see it, the pre-test score can be a controlled variable in MANCOVA, with the post-test score a the dependent, and the two groups as the independent variable.
I must add that the average pre-test score for both groups was the same, if it matters.
I appreciate your opinions and suggestions.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

https://openpublishing.library.umass.edu/pare/article/1509/galley/1460/view/ is part of the extensive literature that addresses your question.  Quasi-experimentation by Cook and Campbell has a good chapter on this too.

I do share your confusion about your colleague's suggestion, but he may have a point. It will depend on what you are trying to prove, or what question you are trying to answer, and it will depend also on exactly what your pre/post scores are (more on this later).
The simplest, most obvious way to handle your data would be to look at the paired differences (post-pre), for both the control and intervention group, and use a 2-sample t-test (use the Welch t-test, so you do not need to worry about homoscedasticity). This will test if the mean of the paired differences between the 2 groups are significantly different (hence, the intervention had an effect, on average).
You could however also use a Median (Mood) test, also on the paired differences. This will test the median of the paired differences, between the 2 groups. That test has lower power than the t-test (because it is fundamentally a binomial test), so it would depend on your sample size.
One could also think of using the Mann Whitney U test (MWUt), still comparing the paired differences between the 2 groups. It tests a different null hypothesis, specifically the $P(Intervention>Control)+\frac 1 2P(Intervention=Control) > \frac 1 2$ (that is, a random paired difference from the Intervention group will be greater than a random paired difference from the Control group, statistically significantly more often than not, i.e. the Intervention differences are stochastically larger than Control differences, aka stochastic superiority).
Note that all 3 tests are testing a different null; hence one/some may be significant while others are not.
You mention your colleague suggesting a MANOVA; that does not make sense. The pre-scores can not be treated as a DV (the intervention has not yet taken place!). But he might have been suggesting an ANCOVA, which basically is a regression test. You are testing if the intervention had an effect on the post scores, beyond what can be explained by the pre-scores, and that the effect was larger for the intervention group.
If indeed it was an ANCOVA which was suggested, then you really should read the paper linked by @rolando2 in his comment, as well as this paper (free). You would use the post scores as your DV, intervention as your IV (via a dummy variable (0/1)), and the pre scores as a covariate.
One reason some researchers prefer this approach is that paired score differences may not be as "objective" as one would think at first glance. For example, if the scores come from some psychometrics test, large changes are often correlated with low pre-scores (a SAT scores can not be improved above 1600). Also, the fact that the subjects took the same (or similar) tests twice can alone improve the scores (but your experiment has a control group), etc. But on the other hand, if the measures are fairly objective, there is no need to worry about possible biases in the difference scores (e.g. if you measure biomarkers level before and after an intervention, there is no reason to expect bias, censoring, or other issue in the difference scores). This being said, if the reliability of your scores is suspect, I would think any test on these scores ought to be equally suspect.
Note also that the first 3 tests have much "milder" assumptions/requirement than the ANCOVA. T-test requires normality of the paired differences, or a large enough sample size (for CLT to come to the rescue; 30 is generally considered "large enough", unless your data is very "non-normal"). The other 2 require no assumption whatsoever. See this wiki page for the assumptions of the ANCOVA: linearity, homoscedasticity, normality of residuals, etc...
TL;DR: I would use the paired differences, and run a Welch t-test, unless the distributions of the paired differences looked "very non-normal", in which case I would try one the other 2 (Mood median, MWUt).
